# Python subprocess powershell, can't make it work

Tags: python, powershell, subprocess

I have issue with Python 3.12, subprocess and Powershell.

I have a simple Powershell script that do : `systeminfo | Out-File "InfoPc.txt"`

I call this file 0.ps1 and it run fine from powershell.

Now when i try to run it from python like this :

`process=subprocess.Popen(["powershell","0.ps1"]);`

`result=process.communicate()[0]`

`print (result)`

I get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Code\Python\2024\ToolBox\Fonctions\AddMenu.py", line 461, in OpenScript
    process=subprocess.Popen(["C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe","D:\\Code\\Python\\2024\\ToolBox\\99 - Powershell\0.ps1"]);
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Kenta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\Kenta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1538, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
 
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I try to put the path of my powershell, i also try to put the path of my file like this :

```
process=subprocess.Popen(["C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe","D:\\Code\\Python\\2024\\ToolBox\\99 - Powershell\0.ps1"]);
```

Can someone help ?

Comment: In short: use the `-File` parameter to pass the path of a _script file_ to execute to the [PowerShell CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), which is not only generally advisable, but a syntactic necessity for _paths with embedded spaces_.
See the linked duplicate for details.

Comment: Very thank's you ! i was searching since long moments